# Allowing FTP access to a local user without allowing SSH/command line access

Tags: debian, ftp

In former times (as in before Debian Wheezy), you could install FTP as ftpd. It was a neat little tool that came with no extra software and allowed this scenario:

Take a local user, allow him chrooted FTP access to a directory (specified as his home directory) without allowing him SSH/command line access. This was accomplished by adding the user to the `/etc/ftpchroot` file, then taking away his command line interpreter in `/etc/passwd` (change from `/bin/bash` to `/bin/false`).

However, now Debian comes with a new FTP daemon that installs a needlessly complicated superserver which no other service uses (openbsd-inetd). The configuration has changed somehow, and I'm looking for a way to get the old behaviour back.

I've so far set up VSFTPD, but cannot get the FTP access to work when the interactive shell for the local user is `/bin/false`, as the daemon refuses to let the user log in. It works fine while `/bin/bash` is the shell interpreter, but that has the problem that the user could theoretically connect to the system using SSH, something that I surely do not wish.

Is there any way to get either the old configuration (local user, FTP yes, SSH no, CHROOT) back with any other software?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check the file /etc/pam.d/vsftpd, the pam service for vsftpd uses pam_shells.so

pam_shells.so

```
pam_shells is a PAM module that only allows access to the system if the users shell is listed in /etc/shells.

It also checks if /etc/shells is a plain file and not world writable.
```

you only need to add /bin/false to /etc/shells file

Comment: After reading up on what adding /bin/false to /etc/shells does, I'm confident that when not using csh this shouldn't do much, so that is a very good solution. Thank you.

Comment: This doesn't work for me.  /sbin/nologin is already in /etc/shells and using that to disable ssh access prevents vsftp from working as well.

Answer (score 1):

You could use vsftpd's ["virtual users"](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/vsftpd), where users in the virtual users database have only ftp access and nothing else.